# Copy lines in vim to execute in above window opened by ter command?

Tags: python-3.x, vim

I am using the latest vim version.

```
vim --version | head -1
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Aug 12 2019 17:28:55)
```

Edit a python file with vim.

```
vim  embed.py
x = 3 
print(x)
y =4 
print(x+y)
```

Now open a new window with `ter` command in vim.
[image]

The normal way to execute `embed.py` which is in edit status.

```
:! python3 %
```

[image]

New window open and execute `embed.py`.
[image]

I have a new idea,how can copy all the lines in `embed.py` into the above window opened by `ter` command in vim?Show the expected way as below.

[image]
`ggyG` can't work.
Move cursor in vim window,and press `ggyG`.
[image]
Move cursor in the python3 window.
`ctrl + v` can't work, `<C-\><C-N>` can't work too.
It is time to try with gui way,paste nothing also.

[image]
[image]

Do as Tarun Lalwani say:
step1: copy lines into system clipboard

```
:%y+
```

or with other command.

step2: move cursor into the upper window which run python3.
step3: ctrl+v+shift

How can bind all steps with a hot key?
Status 1:

Write the following in my .vimrc.

```
function! CopyPasteBuffer()
     normal gg"+yG
     wincmd p
     call feedkeys('^W"+')
endfunction

nnoremap <leader>p :call CopyPasteBuffer()<CR>
```

`\p` will put `^W"+` on python3's interactive window.
[image]

Status 2:

Write the following in my .vimrc.

```
function! CopyPasteBuffer()
     normal gg"+yG
     wincmd p
endfunction

nnoremap <leader>p :call CopyPasteBuffer()<CR>
```

`\p` will move cursor into upper window,now pressing `ctrl+v+sfift` can take effect.
[image]

Almost done!It remains a issue here.
The last step (step 3) which paste all program's lines into python interactive window haven't been automated into the vimscript,rkta's `CopyPasteBuffer()` only bind two steps with hot key `\p` successfully.
Please have a try in bash ,instead of zsh.
Almost same result both for `normal gg"+yG` and `normal gg"*yG`,`ctrl+v+shift` or `ctrl+w+ctrl+v` or `ctrl+v` can't paste content in register `*` if it is `normal gg"*yG` in `CopyPasteBuffer()`(verified in my bash).

Comment: As usual, yank (`ggyG`) from one window, paste (`p`) to the other. (You will need to be in normal mode in the terminal window, you can use `<C-\><C-N>` to get there if needed.)

Comment: The most important work is to bind all steps with a hot key, system clipboard or not does not matter.

Comment: How to express move cursor into the upper window?I am trying to write a binding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To copy the current buffer, switch to the terminal running in the only split and paste the buffer contents use this function:

```
function! CopyPasteBuffer()
     normal ggyG
     wincmd p
     call feedkeys("\<C-W>\"*")
endfunction
```

(As we are in terminal mode, we need to use <kbd>Ctrl W "</kbd> to paste, see `:h terminal-typing` for other special keys.)

This will paste everything and leave you in the terminal buffer - use <kbd>Ctrl W</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> to switch back.

To bind it to a key use

```
nnoremap <leader>p :call CopyPasteBuffer()<CR>
```

If you didn't rebind your `leader` key you can execute the function with <kbd>\p</kbd>.

---

To use the function with the `*` register just change the function to

```
function! CopyPasteBuffer()
     normal gg"*yG
     wincmd p
     call feedkeys("\<C-W>\"*")
endfunction
```

[image]

Comment: `"*p` means paster, what dows `<C-W>` in `call feedkeys("\<C-W>\"*")` mean?Is there a paste action in `call feedkeys("\<C-W>\"*")`?

Answer (score 5):

There is a built-in function named `term_sendkeys` to send keys to a terminal buffer.

Here is a oneliner to send all lines in the current buffer to the first terminal window using `term_sendkeys`:

```vim
:cal term_sendkeys(term_list()[0], join(map(getbufline(bufnr('.'), 1, '$'), 'v:val . "\n"'), ''))
```

You can simply define a map to execute the oneliner in your `.vimrc` like this:

```vim
nnoremap <leader>p :<c-u>cal term_sendkeys(term_list()[0], join(map(getbufline(bufnr('.'), 1, '$'), 'v:val . "\n"'), ''))<Cr>
```

However oneliners are bit hard to understand at glance, so it is better to define this as a function and define a map to call it:

```vim
function! s:SendLinesToTerm()
  let term_buf = term_list()[0]
  let lines = getbufline(bufnr('.'), 1, '$')
  let str = join(map(lines, 'v:val . "\n"'), '')

  cal term_sendkeys(term_buf, str)
endfunction
nnoremap <leader>p :call <SID>SendLinesToTerm()<Cr>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to understand that when you yank the lines in `vim` it is not basically going to system's clipboard. The `terminal` shown in the upper window can only interact with the system's clipboard

You can see the below thread on how to use system clipboard

https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/84/how-can-i-copy-text-to-the-system-clipboard-from-vim

I use mac which has `pbcopy` to copy to the clipboard. So I can execute something like `:silent !pbcopy < %`. This will copy the file to clipboard. And then a normal `CTRL+V` or `CTRL+SHIFT+V` or `CMD+V` would work based on your OS

For unix you would use something like `xclip`

[image: Working]

Comment: Can bind a hot key  with the whole steps?

Comment: @rkta, I will check

Answer (score 0):

#### How to use the terminal window

According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54734174) and @Amadan’s comment, in a terminal window, the command <kbd>ctrl-w</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> (capital N) allows to exit the “insertion mode” (so that you can copy things from the terminal window); also, <kbd>ctrl-w</kbd><kbd>"</kbd> followed by the appropriate register name (`*` for X primary, `+` for X clipboard) allows to paste the contents of the said register (that’s what you are interested in). You may also paste the primary register with <kbd>ctrl-insert</kbd>, and the clipboard register with the window menu you show on one of your screenshots.

#### How to use registers

On registers: long story short, Vim stores yanked text in various named [registers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997078). If you are running Vim from an X graphical environment, the Vim register `*` is connected to the X clipboard “primary” (usually the last text selected with the mouse from within a graphical application), and the Vim register `+` is connected to the X clipboard “clipboard” (usually the last text copied with the shortcut <kbd>ctrl-v</kbd> from within a graphical application). By default, Vim puts text yanked with the command <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> in the register `*`, but you can put it in `+` as well, and you can change the default to `+` (`set clipboard=unnamedplus`).

Use whichever register you prefer. Only make sure you use the same when copying and pasting (*i.e.*, by default <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> will typically copy to X primary while the window menu will paste from the X clipboard).

*Official source:* Read `:help terminal` to learn how to use Vim’s terminal windows, and `:help registers` for Vim’s registers.

<sub>(*Credible source:* Google PageRank.)</sub>

---

However in your case, aren’t you looking rather at the Python keyword for importing a file into the REPL? Although I don’t know Python very well, it should probably looks like `import embed` or something.

Comment: Dont need import; OP wants to use a sort of interactive repl, with a send-line-to-repl or send-file-to-repl command (a bit like slime, if youve ever used it for lisp).